# Best way to limit concurrent http requests in python (no threads)?

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping

I am interested in creating a pool for asynchronous function calls (they will be HTTP requests) however I would like to do everything in a single thread. The reason for this is that spawning multiple threads will waste resources (the thread does nothing but wait for the response).

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

import some_library as pool

POOL_LIMIT = 3

urls = ["example.com/28409078",
"example.com/31145880",
"example.com/54622752",
"example.com/48008963",
"example.com/82016326",
"example.com/75587921",
"example.com/2988065",
"example.com/47574087",
"example.com/13478021",
"example.com/46041669"]

def get(url):
  # return some promise here

# now perform the async operations
pool(limit=POOL_LIMIT, urls, get)
```

Is there a python library which can manage async pools for me? In Node.js it looks like there is a library which does something close to what I'd like to do: https://github.com/rxaviers/async-pool

Comment: Can you mention which library are you using?

Comment: i'm using `asyncio` and `aiohttp` if that helps

Comment: The `asyncio` library is single threaded by design. If you want to limit concurrency use [semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore). Note also that by default, aiohttp's client session allows 100 concurrent connections. See https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#limiting-connection-pool-size for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I've Implemented a pool using basic `asyncio` functions.

WORKING:

- pool starts with maxsize tasks
- when first task completes, it adds next task to queue and prints its result
- similarly for each single task completes, it adds another tasks until maxsize

Code:

```
import asyncio

async def pool(tasks, maxsize=3):
    pending = [asyncio.create_task(tasks.pop(0)) for _ in range(maxsize) if tasks]
    while pending:
        (done, pending) = await asyncio.wait(pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        while True:
             if (not tasks) or (len(pending) >= maxsize):
                  break
             pending.add(asyncio.create_task(tasks.pop(0)))
        for task in done:
             print(task.result())
    print("POOL COMPLETED")
```

For an example you can create tasks and pool like here:

```
async def work(index, sleep_time):
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
    return f"task {index} done"

tasks = [work(i, 1) for i in range(10)]
```

Now to run the task call the asyncio.run

```
asyncio.run(pool(tasks, 3))
```

This will only run 3 tasks in parallel

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a popular lobrary for this. Here's a straightforward way to do that:

```
async def get(url):
  # return some promise here

async def processQueue():
  while len(urls):
    url = urls.pop()
    await get(url)

async def main():
  await asyncio.gather(
    processQueue(),
    processQueue(),
    processQueue()
  )

asyncio.run(main())
```

You might need a lock before the pop(), I'm not sure.